# UART3 in Google Coral transmitting but not receiving

Tags: uart, tpu

I am using Google Coral DevKit and I  would like to connect UART3 (ttymxc2) with external device, I connect it to FTDI for debugging and I could send from coral but I couldn't receive. I managed to use UART1 Transmit & Receive Successfully. But my requirement is to use UART3.

any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating OS to latest version